# How to remove halo after click from buttons in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm making a button in Bootstrap and it looks fine.  However, whenever I click on the button, at least in chrome, it displays a blue halo glow around the edges of the button until I click some other part of the screen.  Is there a way to eliminate this blue glow?

I have seen this question asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999328/how-to-remove-the-border-from-search-box-after-clicking
but the only answer was a comment to add `.yourbox:focus { border: 0 !important; }` to the stylesheet.  I did that and added the class "yourbox" to the button, but it didn't change anything.  This is the current code for my button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
Button
</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing the outline on `focus` should help you out, tested.

```
.btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Thomas another quick try is `outline: 0 none;` make sure it's applied and not overwritten by other rules.

Comment: You know what, I think the Bootstrap css was overriding my stylesheet.  I put the reference to my stylesheet after my reference to the Bootstrap instead of before it and that seemed to have solved the problem.  Thank you everyone though for your help!

Comment: @Thomas glad to hear that, so this is working, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

```
.form-control:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
.btn:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

If the above doesn't work too, then remove the outline from every input property with the following:

```
textarea:focus, 
input[type="text"]:focus, 
input[type="password"]:focus, 
input[type="datetime"]:focus, 
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus, 
input[type="date"]:focus, 
input[type="month"]:focus, 
input[type="time"]:focus, 
input[type="week"]:focus, 
input[type="number"]:focus, 
input[type="email"]:focus, 
input[type="url"]:focus, 
input[type="search"]:focus, 
input[type="tel"]:focus, 
input[type="color"]:focus, 
.uneditable-input:focus {   
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
}

select:focus {
   outline-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried this also, but it doesn't work either.  It does make the height of the button smaller on hover, but that's all it seems to be doing.

Comment: box-shadow: 0; isn't a valid property value. box-shadow: none; instead

Comment: @Azodium Thanks for the heads up mate. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

The focus have 3 parameters :

```
.your_class:focus {
        border-color: #66AFE9;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
        outline: 0 none;
    }
```

Disable them

```
.your_class:focus {
        border: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        outline: 0 none !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the halo from link use below css code.

```
.btn:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```